# realtime output from program in python in GUI

Tags: python, subprocess, gtk3, python-multithreading

i am writing a graphical shell for a command-line program in python using GTK. The main program has output like this:

```
Starting Tractor:

Dec 04 22:10:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Dec 04 22:10:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Dec 04 22:10:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Dec 04 22:10:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Dec 04 22:10:37.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Tractor is conneted.
```

I have a start button which starts the program via subprocess. since I want the main window to be operative during the start process, I used thrading for that. Here is my code:

```
def on_start_clicked(self, button):
    spinner = Gtk.Spinner()
    self.props.icon_widget = spinner
    spinner.start()
    self.show_all()
    header_bar = self.get_parent()
    if self.is_running():
        def task_thread():
            task = Popen(command + "stop", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
            task.wait()
            spinner.stop()
            header_bar.show_progress_button(False)
            self.update_label()
    else:
        def task_thread():
            header_bar.show_progress_button(True)
            task = Popen(command + "start", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
            while True:
                output = task.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
                if output == '' and task.poll() is not None:
                    break
                if output and '%' in output:
                    print(output.split()[5][:-2])
            task.wait()
            spinner.stop()
            self.update_label()

    thread = Thread(target=task_thread)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```

The problem is that the log output is not realtime, but it waits until the whole process to be complete and then prints the whole output altogether!

I want the actual percentage at the time, in order to pass it to a progress bar, showing how much of the task is done. How can I accomplish that?

## EDIT

I changed the code as following thanks to [theGtknerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6150775/thegtknerd), but the feed function still works after the process is done and just prints the first line of the whole output. I think here is a malfunction in when IO_IN is triggered.

```
def thread_finished (self, stdout, condition):
    GLib.source_remove(self.io_id)
    stdout.close()
    self.spinner.stop()
    self.update_label()
    print("heeey")
    return False

def feed (self, stdout, condition):
    line = stdout.readline()
    line = line.decode("utf-8")
    print(line)
    return True

def on_start_clicked(self, button):
    self.spinner = Gtk.Spinner()
    self.props.icon_widget = self.spinner
    self.spinner.start()
    self.show_all()
    header_bar = self.get_parent()
    if self.is_running():
        header_bar.show_progress_button(False)
        task = Popen(command + "stop", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    else:
        header_bar.show_progress_button(True)
        task = Popen(command + "start", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    self.io_id = GLib.io_add_watch(task.stdout, GLib.IO_IN, self.feed)
    GLib.io_add_watch(task.stdout, GLib.IO_HUP, self.thread_finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example for you to learn from. So in my Python file I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, GObject
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import os, sys


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        window = Gtk.Window()
        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        window.add(self.label)
        window.show_all()
        window.connect("destroy", self.on_window_destroy)

        p = Popen(['./long_run.sh'], stdout = PIPE,stderr = STDOUT,stdin = PIPE)
        self.io_id = GObject.io_add_watch(p.stdout, GObject.IO_IN, self.feed)
        GObject.io_add_watch(p.stdout, GObject.IO_HUP, self.thread_finished)

    def feed (self, stdout, condition):
        line = stdout.readline()
        line = line.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
        self.label.set_label(line)
        return True

    def thread_finished (self, stdout, condition):
        GObject.source_remove(self.io_id)
        stdout.close()
        self.label.set_label("Hurray, all done!")

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()
        print ("shutdown")

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

And in the file long_run.sh I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Loading, please wait..."
sleep 5
echo "10%"
sleep 5
echo "20%"
sleep 5
echo "30%"
sleep 5
echo "40%"
sleep 5
echo "50%"
sleep 5
echo "60%"
sleep 5
echo "70%"
sleep 5
echo "80%"
sleep 5
echo "90%"
sleep 5
echo "100%"
sleep 5
```

Comment: Great way. I changed the function like [this](https://gitlab.com/tractor-team/carburetor/blob/67e50debe4af6b150ea7d3dcb95170044996b674/carburetor#L93) and there is some improvements in overall code, but the feed function still works after the process is done and just prints the first line of the whole output. Have you any idea about that? I think there is a malfunction in when IO_IN is triggered.

Comment: You may want to try `task = Popen([command,  "start"], stdout=PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)`.

Comment: I know I have seen the problem that you are describing myself, but it was a long time ago and I forget how I fixed it.

Comment: I fixed it by flushing the buffer after each print in the source app via setting `flush=True` in `print` commands.